How to Display Overall Percentage Grand Total for Specific Rows in a Spotfire Cross Table
I'm using Spotfire to create a cross table and I'm facing an issue with displaying the grand total as an overall percentage for specific rows. Here's a description of my problem:
I have a cross table where:

The vertical axis lists different measures.
The horizontal axis represents dates.
The cell values currently show the sum of values.

I want to modify the cross table such that for specific measures (those containing "%" in their name), the grand total should be displayed as an overall percentage (monthly average) rather than a simple sum of percentages.
example table
For the measures that include "%" in their name, the grand total should be calculated as an overall percentage (monthly average), while for other measures, it should remain as the sum.
I have created the cross table and formatted the values for rows A4% and A5% as Percentage, but I am unsure if it is possible to set the grand total as the average of these percentage values.

Percentages are all numbers divided by 100, so summing up is fine. The % sign simply indicates the formatting of e.g. 0.05 as 5%. Sub-averages, which I think is what you mean, cannot be summed up.
